# Probability to winning chess

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Two players A and B are playing the final of chess championship which contains a series of matches. Draw is not considered

The probability that A wins is 2/3.

The probability that B wins is 1/3.

The winner will be A if wins at least 12 games and the winner will be B if wins at least 6 games.

we're given that A has won 8 games, and B has won 4 games. who is now most likely to win the championship?

sorry for my english ^ _ ^

Comment: So A now has to win 4 games and B has to win 2?

Comment: I believe so...I would think that it's $15$ choices for rearranging the wins and losses. We need to find the cases where both wins for B come before A.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's indeed the question: we're *given* that $A$ has won 8 games, and $B$ has won $4$ games ... who is now most likely to win the championship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we have here is a negative binomial.

$A$ must do one of the following to win:

Win $4$ consecutive games

Win $3$ of the next $4$ games and then win the $5th$ game.

Otherwise, $B$ would have won $2$ games and the game would be over.

We have $n$ trials given $k$ successes where

$${n-1\choose{k-1}}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Using our numbers,

$${3\choose{3}}{\frac{2}{3}}^4\frac{1}{3}^{0}+{4\choose{3}}{\frac{2}{3}}^4\frac{1}{3}^{1}\approx 0.4609$$

Thus $B$ has a greater chance of winning.

Just to check:

The probability that $B$ wins would be

$${1\choose{1}}{\frac{1}{3}}^2\frac{2}{3}^{0}+{2\choose{1}}{\frac{1}{3}}^2\frac{2}{3}^{1}+{3\choose{1}}{\frac{1}{3}}^2\frac{2}{3}^{2}+{4\choose{1}}{\frac{1}{3}}^2\frac{2}{3}^{3}\approx 0.5391$$

which is the compliment of the probability that $A$ wins, as expected.

Comment: Nicely done! Like your check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be modeled through a Markov chain:
[image]

Red arrows represent transitions with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and green arrows represent transitions with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. The transition matrix is 
$$ P=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

and the probability that $B$ wins is 
$$\left(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\right)\,P^5 \left(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1\right)^T = \color{red}{\frac{131}{243}}.$$

Comment: That’s very interesting; I’ve never seen such an approach. I’m upvoting for sheer interestingness.

Comment: @JackDaurizio  How did you figure out $P^5$? By hand? Some handy program? Online matrix multiplier?

Comment: @Bram28: I let Mathematica perform the computation, through the $\text{MatrixPower}$ command.